# Delphi 5 causes EAccessViolation when manifest is added as a resource

Tags: delphi, exception, manifest, compatibility, comctl32

This is one of most interesting problems I have found recently.
We have a legacy Delphi 5 program (Rave Reports 4 references are preventing from upgrading to D2007).

When program is compiled with our template-generated version resource it works fine. The problem arises when also template-generated manifest resource is added to a program's dpr.

Manifest is a "generic", ASCII file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">

  <assemblyIdentity
    name="Name"
    processorArchitecture="x86"
    version="2.0.0.0"
    type="win32"/>

  <description>Desc</description>

  <dependency>
      <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity
              type="win32"
              name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
              version="6.0.0.0"
              processorArchitecture="x86"
              publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
              language="*"
          />
      </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>

  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>

  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"> 
    <application> 
      <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/> 
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
    </application> 
  </compatibility>

</assembly>
```

In App.dpr there is a manifest resource reference:

```
{$R 'manifest.res' 'manifest.rc'}
```

Manifest is compiled by calling:

```
C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi5\Bin\brcc32.exe manifest.rc
```

And when program is started following exception is raised:

```
exception class   : EAccessViolation
exception message : Access violation at address 75A1A890 in module 'KERNELBASE.dll'. Read of address 00000001.
```

Call stack for main thread:

```
main thread ($1144):
75a1a890 +007 KERNELBASE.dll
75a1a97c +069 KERNELBASE.dll          WideCharToMultiByte
73f28764 +048 comctl32.dll            #342
777741f4 +016 user32.dll              CallWindowProcA
00092de2 +0ca app.exe        Controls TWinControl.DefaultHandler
0009336c +01c app.exe        Controls TWinControl.WMNotify
000c2454 +024 app.exe        ComCtrls TCustomListView.WMNotify
00090249 +111 app.exe        Controls TControl.WndProc
00092d0a +1d2 app.exe        Controls TWinControl.WndProc
000c39ea +072 app.exe        ComCtrls TCustomListView.WndProc
0009290c +02c app.exe        Controls TWinControl.MainWndProc
000a5880 +014 app.exe        Forms    StdWndProc
77757690 +044 user32.dll              SendMessageW
777741f4 +016 user32.dll              CallWindowProcA
000c1e6f +0c7 app.exe        ComCtrls TCustomListView.HeaderWndProc
000a5880 +014 app.exe        Forms    StdWndProc
7763642b +02b ntdll.dll               KiUserCallbackDispatcher
77753573 +00a user32.dll              DispatchMessageA
000ae8c7 +083 app.exe        Forms    TApplication.ProcessMessage
000ae8fe +00a app.exe        Forms    TApplication.HandleMessage
000aeb09 +081 app.exe        Forms    TApplication.Run
00186ecf +077 app.exe        mca      initialization
75b61192 +010 kernel32.dll            BaseThreadInitThunk
```

Linked comctl32.dll:

```
73f00000 comctl32.dll            6.10.7600.16385    C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7600.16385_none_421189da2b7fabfc
```

From what I can see the problem is bound with some Delphi 5 incompatibilities with comctl32.dll controls. I updated Delphi VCL to most recent one. Is there any other solution than just migrating to D2007 ?

Comment: Migrating to Delphi 2007 is a good idea. Then you're only four years out of date instead of 12.

Comment: For off the shelf software I couldn't agree more. Yet this is a "one time" old bespoke app "refreshment" and the job is compensated accordingly. Delphi 2007 upgrade is painless as long as Rave is not involved. Delphi 2009 up not necessarily so (I'm talking dailywtf  qualifying code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need more that just the manifest if I recall correctly. You also need [Mike Lischke's theme manager component](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=17&Itemid=33). This code eventually found its way into Delphi 7.

Comment: Yes, that was it. As a side effect, application now looks better - thanks.

Comment: Just to add a little bit to this answer, if you have a Windows 7 (or 2008 server) without a theme (because of DC politics), at least on 64-bit versions, you get this error too... the only answer i have found is to completely remove Themes.